# Get the ISP of an IP in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, whois

Is there a way to perform a whois on an IP to get the ISP that provides that IP in a Node.js/Express server ?

I already got the IP, I'm not looking for a way to get the client's IP.

I've found ways with external request to paid services that sends back JSON, but I would like to find a native way.

Do you guys know anything that could help me ?

**Edit:** I'm not trying to build a whois server, I just need for the application I build to get the client's ISP name.

Comment: are you saying you would like to implement whois client in node.js?

Comment: Not at all. I would like to use one.

Comment: You mean use an existing service that's free?

Comment: I'm thinking more as a way to get the info as an NSLOOKUP command in a Linux terminal. I just need the ISP NAME from an IP address. I don't specially need a existing service.

Comment: starting to feel this is a "do work for me for free" gig...

Comment: Not at all. I just wanted to know if there is a way to replicate in node the NSLOOKUP command. I'm willing to implement everything myself otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get ISP information by using node-whois module but in its response it quite complex to access value for a particular key. So there is another way is you can use satellite module, This module can give quick response and response is available in json format so you can access any key values easily.
Here is the code.

```
var satelize = require('satelize');
var ExternalIP = "173.194.70.100"; // I asume that, you already have external(public)IP
satelize.satelize({ip: ExtenalIP}, function(err, geoData) 
{

     if(err){
        console.log(" Error in retriving ISP Information");  
     }
     else
     {
        console.log("ISP Information for "+ ExternalIP+" :"+geoData );
     }
});
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the satelite npm module. Would be nice.

Answer (score 6):

<s>[This](https://npmjs.org/package/whoisclient) is a Node.js module implementing a whois client.</s>

As correctly pointed out by @robertklep, the above module does not work with IP addresses. Still, [node-whois](https://npmjs.org/package/node-whois) does (I personally tested the code this time):

```
"use strict";

var whois = require('node-whois');

whois.lookup('173.194.70.100', function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

The only issue is that the output is not very nice.

Comment: Did you try passing it an IP-number?

Comment: The issue with your updated solution is that it can refer to other WHOIS servers that need to be searched to get the actual ISP the IP-number is assigned to (via the `ReferralServer` property).

Comment: The output style isn't the only issue. It gives you the name of the RIR for that IP, then I would have to make a request to the RIPE DB to get more info. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/xreader/whois has nice JSON output. Hope this helps somebody.